# Convert SQL query into lambda expression in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-to-linq-conversion

How can I convert a SQL query like this:

```sql
Select * 
from product
where c_id = 2
```

into a lambda expression?

I tried writing it like this:

```cs
db.Products.Where(x => x.c_id == 2).ToList()
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Have you tried this in code?

Comment: Give it a try and let us know :p

Comment: I am already trying it. it does not work

Comment: It should work @TaseenTahir..it's totally perfect query..

Comment: Query is perfect!!!..Just verify c_id datatype in database if it's long or int then it is correct or it's string then you should try double(") quotes.

Comment: Provide us with how you're implementing this because, as @ankitkanojia said, this query is correctly constructed, assuming a property called c_id exists in the Products table.

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.Products.OrderByDescending(x => x.pro_id).ToList());
        }

Comment: i am implementing like this because in one page i want view only c_id = 1 id data and other is c_id 2 data

Comment: Please add that code to your question, where it can be better formatted. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredResult = db.Products.Where(x => x.c_id ==2 ).ToList();
```

should work, provided db.Products is collection.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this correct?

**Yes**

If you want to `OrderBy` along with `Where`, you can try this way

```
public ActionResult Index() { 
    return View(db.Products.Where(x => x.c_id == 2).OrderByDescending(x => x.pro_id).ToList()); 
}
```